# How to refresh update site in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, update-site

Currently if I change contents of Eclipse update site, I have to restart Eclipse to see new contents. Is there a way to make it without restart?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open Preference Page
2. Select Install/Update > Available Software Sites.
3. Choose your update site to refresh, then Press [Reload] Button.